# PHP script on server request (apache)

Tags: php, apache, request

I want to make my own custom logging script on my Apache2 webserver.
It should be executed on **every** server request (POST, GET, etc.) and then write some information into my database.

My problem is: I don't now how to trigger the execution.

I have searched (Google) for handlers in apache. "addHandler/setHandler" in apache2.conf. But these are just executed if a special file is requested.

And putting a script on each of my pages is no option too. Just because I can't put a script to a requested image.

Is there any option in config files to do something like:

```
onRequest var/www/html/customLog.php
```

I woud prefer `.php` or `.sh`. Thank you for giving a hint.

P.S. I'm running my server on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably with [`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog), you can log everything described in [custom log formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) which should cover everything you might want to log, and you can [pipe it to a program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped) which could be PHP or a shell script as you like, for logging it to your database.